# Apply for the transit Schengen visa from the the States

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, transit

Can I apply for the transit Schengen visa in the States? Is it still required to have your US visa valid 3 months before your return to the States? Or you don't need that for the transit visa.

Comment: Do you even need an airport transit visa? Very few nationalities actually need one of these. What country issued your passport? What is your proposed itinerary?

Comment: See https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en to find out if you need a visa